# Javadoc formatting broken since upgrading to Java 7

Tags: java, javadoc, java-7

Since upgrading my project to Java 7, the generated documentation now has broken formatting.

How to fix this?

Comment: How is it broken? Any live example? What's the javadoc code generating the broken part?

Comment: The pages generate successfully, but the layout looks incorrect. For example, links that normally appear horizontally across the top of the page would appear vertically, as a list. There's no live version that I can point you to as I won't publish the broken version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 7 changed the CSS stylesheet used by Javadoc, as the documentation now has different formatting of various page elements.

You can download the correct stylesheet from Oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/stylesheet.css

Comment: If you simply delete the old stylesheet.css file from the directory into which you're generating the Javadocs, it will generate a new one that formats the docs. correctly.  I'm not sure why it doesn't overwrite that file by default - perhaps it's assuming you might have customized the styles (which has to be extremely rare).

Comment: @KevinRahe, in my case I had modified it. Good to know that it'll regenerate it. In either case any changes would have to be remade.

Comment: It's interesting how a solution at one level (CSS eliminates the need to include style information in the HTML and makes it easy to apply blanket changes to the style of a series of related pages) creates a new problem at another (resolving customized and generated CSS), suggesting perhaps yet another level of abstraction.  (No, please don't go there!)

Comment: Ideally javadoc would allow you to specify the version of javadoc formatting that you want to use, so as to avoid this issue i.e. letting you run javadoc with a flag such as `--target-version 1.6`. I just checked and no, they don't [Oracle Javadoc docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html)